# SQL query (Join without duplicates)

Tags: sql, postgresql, having

I have tables `users` and `topics`. Every user can have from 0 to several topics (one-to-many relationship).

How I can get only those users which have at least one topic?

I need all columns from users (without columns from topics) and without duplicates in table `users`. In last column I need number of topics.

**UPDATED:**

Should be like this:

```
SELECT user.*, count(topic.id) 
FROM ad
LEFT JOIN topic ON user.id = topic.ad
GROUP BY user.id
HAVING count(topic.id) > 0;
```

but it takes 0 result. But it should not be 0.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, give an example of your tables and expected results. And maybe what you have tried so far.

Comment: Read up on SQL Joins and post what you've tried, then you can get better answers.

Comment: added sql, please, see

Comment: few problems ...  select user.* can't work ... list all columns and group by all columns (of table users that is), use inner join instead of left join and you selecting from table "ad" and doing join on table users ... that doesn't make sense

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Comment: @Veljko89: I know your comment was _before_ annoirq stated the used DBMS, but `select user.*` does indeed work as it included the primary key of the table. So it's enough to do a `group by` on the PK column as all other attributes are functional dependent on the grouping column. This behavior is defined in the SQL standard and Postgres does support this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly you need to have your two tables, because you have left limited  information about your table structure I will use an example to explain how this works, you should then be able to easily apply this to your own tables.

Firstly you need to have two tables (which you do)

Table "user"

```
id | name
1  | Joe Bloggs
2  | Eddy Ready
```

Table "topic"

```
topicid | userid | topic
      1 |      1 | Breakfast
      2 |      1 | Lunch
      3 |      1 | Dinner
```

Now asking for a count against each user is done using the follwing;

```
SELECT user.name, count(topic.topicid) 
FROM user
INNER JOIN topic ON user.id = topic.userid
GROUP BY user.name
```

If you use a left join, this will include records from the "user" table which does not have any rows in the "topic" table, however if you use an INNER JOIN this will ONLY include users who have a matching value in both tables.

I.e. because the user id "2" (which we use to join) is not listed in the topic table you will not get any results for this user.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

use inner join   and distinct

```
select distinct user_table.id
from user_table 
inner join topics_table on topic_table.user_id = user_table.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id
, u.name
, count(b.topicName)
from user u
left join topic t on t.userid = u.id
group by u.id, u.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select topic number per user and then join it with user data. Something like this:

```
with t as
(
select userid, count(*) as n
from topic
group by userid
)
SELECT user.*, t.n
FROM user
JOIN t ON user.id = t.userid
```